# Finding an explicit formula for $a_n$ defined recursively by $a_{n+1}=2a_n\frac{(n+2)}{n+1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

for n = 1 ; $a_{1}= 1 $

---

I tried to apply iteration to this recurrence relation with no success. 
How can I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$a_{n+1}=2a_n\frac{(n+2)}{n+1}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{n+2}=2\frac{a_n}{n+1}$$

Define $b_n=\frac{a_n}{n+1}$ and this becomes quite simple.

Comment: Thanks! what was motivation behind that?

Comment: @Dota. Typical trick !